# OpenLDAP being very slow

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, openldap

I've inherited an OpenLDAP installation which suddenly seems to be extremely slow to respond to queries, breaking many client applications. I've checked the basics; server has plenty of memory free, disk is fine, there's not much I/O load. I'm also unable to get slapd to log anything unless I run it manually; if I do, everything looks fine except that every operation seems to take around one second, which is of course glacial.

It is OpenLDAP 2.4.40 and I'm running CentOS 6.4. OpenLDAP seems to be using OLC which I find tricky to deal with, but I've tried setting the log level and it STILL doesn't log. CentOS also doesn't seem to package the BDB admin tools for OpenLDAP and I'm afraid to just grab some random version off the net to try to recover the database with in case there's an incompatibility that corrupts everything (although I suppose I could do that and just make a copy of the database first, which I'd do anyhow...)

I'd greatly appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

By default OpenLDAP logs to `local4`.

`/etc/rsyslog.d/slapd.conf`

```
local4.*    /var/log/messages
```

For logging you'll also want to set `olcLogLevel` to an appropriate value in `cn=config`.

`olcDBIndex` is your friend.

Under CentOS7 the standard thing to do is use mdb rather than bdb. Though even on CentOS6 you should have an hdb.

Comment: Yes, rsyslog is configured with local4.* to /var/log/ldap.log, but there is still nothing coming into that file.

Comment: Also it does seem to use BDB. /var/lib/ldap is full of .bdb files.

Comment: @anksil What's your current `olcLogLevel`?